# Areas of polygons and circles

Tags: geometry

If the area (A=1/2aP) and the perimeter of a regular polygon are numerically equal, find the length of the apothem of the regular polygon.  How do I do that if there's no given information like numbers?

Comment: In the formula $A=\frac12aP$, what are $A$, $a$, and $P$? If they are what I think they are, the answer to the question is nearly right there in the question itself.

Comment: @David K a is the apothem and p is the perimeter

Comment: And $A$ is area, right? And you are given that the area and perimeter are numerically equal--so $A=P$, is that correct?

Comment: @David K yes that is correct

Answer (score 1):

We know that $A=\frac{1}{2}aP$, where $A$ is the area, $a$ is the apothem, and $P$ is the perimeter. We also know that $A=P \implies \frac{A}{P}=1$.

Therefore, $A=\frac{1}{2}aP \implies \frac{A}{P}=\frac{1}{2}a \implies 1=\frac{1}{2}a \implies 2=a$. Thus, the apothem of this regular polygon is 2.

Answer (score 0):

You have one formula, $A=\frac12 aP$, that is generally true of any
regular polygon, and moreover you have the formula
$A = P$ which is true of a particular regular polygon mentioned
in the problem statement.

The fact that $A = P$ means that you can use $A$ or $P$ interchangeably
in any formula describing this particular polygon: $A$ and $P$ are the
same number. So the formula
$$A=\frac12 aP$$
can also (for this polygon) be written
$$P=\frac12 aP$$
(substituting $P$ instead of $A$).
Assuming the polygon is not degenerate, you know that $P \neq 0$,
so you can divide by $P$ on both sides of the equation.
It is then easy to find the value of $a$.

(If degenerate polygons are allowed, then you get two possible values
for $a$. It seems unlikely that this was the intended interpretation
of the problem.)